# Axios/ Ajax posting data issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios, magento2

I’m trying to learn react so I’m rebuilding the magento2 minicart in react, all seems to be working well apart from I’m having issues submitting the form data if the quantity changes - I’m trying to do this like so:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ qty: e.target.value }, () => {
        axios({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'post',
            url: '/checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/',
            data: {
                item_id: 13,
                item_qty: this.state.qty,
                form_key: 'KTC30XGNGahjfVmn'
            }
        });
    });
}
```

On a refresh of the page the basket quantity doesn’t update, when checking how default mangento2 posts the information it seems to be different as you can see on the images - how can I change my code above so it matches the default post if that’s the issue?

My axios post:
[image]

Default M2 post:
[image]

Update: changing params to data makes the request 302 and changes the type to HTML and can't seem to get it back to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably an M2 specific solution but it needed to be built up as a form like below so it submits it as form data:

```
let addToCartForm = new FormData();
    addToCartForm.set('item_id', this.props.item_id);
    addToCartForm.set('item_qty', this.state.qty);
    addToCartForm.set('form_key', document.getElementsByName('form_key')[0].value);

    axios({
        url: '/checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/',
        method: 'post',
        data: addToCartForm
    }).then(() => {
         window.updateCartData();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`params` is to send data in query parameter. To send data in post `body` use `body` option. Like this:

**Edit**

Since you are submitting form data, you need to specify content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and also need to change way how we send data.

```
         axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/',
                headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: queryString.stringify({
                    item_id: 9,
                    item_qty: this.state.qty,
                    form_key: 'KTC30XGNGahjfVmn'
                })
            });
         });
```

You can get query string module using from here https://github.com/Gozala/querystring#readme

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did try this before and thought it was wrong as the status changes to 302 and the type to html, I'm guessing this is to do with the headers? I've added this onto the code in the question

Comment: 302 is status code for redirect. Looks like server is redirecting you to some other page, that's why you are getting html in response.
Anyway looking at second image I realized that it sending data as form url encoded. I changed code for that. Please let me know it works.